# How to add comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add comments to post model. This is my comments_controller so far:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_post

    def index
        @comments = @post.comments.order('id')
    end

    def new
        @comment = @post.comments.new
    end

    def create
        @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
        @comment.user = current_user
        @comment.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:comment_body)
    end

    def find_post
        @user = current_user
        @post = @user.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    end
end
```

I get this error:

> NoMethodError in CommentsController#new undefined method `posts' for
>   nil:NilClass

as you can see I'm new to programming. Thanks for help!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you get the error when you are not signed in. Method `find_post` is called every time because of `before_action :find_post`. If you are not signed in, then `current_user` is `nil`, and you call `posts` for `nil`.